# Modifying an array from google api to create a dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a simple dataframe with Pandas.  I am using a python script to get the distance matrix between all addresses stored in an array.  I am successful in creating an array of values, but DataFrame needs an array of arrays.

```
import googlemaps
import pandas as pd

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='MYKEY')
addys = ['New York, NY','Boston, MA']
addyMeters = []

for origin in addys:
    for dest in addys:
        directions = gmaps.distance_matrix(origin , dest)
        meters = directions['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']
        addyMeters.append(meters)
print(addyMeters) #Result: [0, 349157, 346651, 0]


df = pd.DataFrame(addyMeters, columns=addys, index=addys)
print(df)
```

addyMeters gives me

```
[0, 349157, 346651, 0]
```

But what I need for the DataFrame is:

```
[[0, 349157],[[346651, 0]]
```

Hopeful end result mileage table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities. One is to create a 2D list, and the other is to create a 1D array, and reshape.

**Option 1**
2D list -

```
addyMeters = []

for origin in addys:
    addyMeters.append([])
    for dest in addys:
        ...
        addyMeters[-1].append(meters)

df = pd.DataFrame(addyMeters, columns=addys, index=addys)
```

---

**Option 2**
Initialise and reshape a 1D array. This is possible since your resultant will be square.

```
x = np.array(addyMeters).reshape(-1, int(len(addyMeters) ** .5))
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=addys, index=addys)
```

If your data has a shape of `5 X 5` then `len(addyMeters)` gives `25`.